# .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid - cannot resolve clr-namespace for Components.Routes

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, .net-8.0, hybrid

Created a new.net8.0 MAUI Blazor Hybrid App (New solution). Built solution and got the error:

> XFC0000   Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:MauiApp1:Components.Routes"

Code is all stock but here it is.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Components.Routes}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>

</ContentPage>
```

Routes.Razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(MauiProgram).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: please do NOT post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error on a completely fresh MAUI Blazor Hybrid App in Visual Studio. There must have been a problem with this introduced in .NET SDK 8.0.2.

I downgraded my .NET SDK install to v8.0.1 and the problem was fixed for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Routes.razor's default namespace is the project name(MauiApp1). So you can try to change it as:

```
<RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Routes}" />
```

And then if you want to use `ComponentType="{x:Type local:Components.Routes}`, please make sure you have moved the **Routes.razor** into the Components folder.

Comment: Thanks,.  The above code is unedited from MS (File - New project), the Routes.razor file is in Components folder by default. i've changed nothing.  I have tried troubleshooting this and i've tried to move Routes file to root and made the changes oy listed with the same result.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your project? I created a new .net8.0 MAUI Blazor Hybrid App and the default code is `<RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Routes}" />` @RAMMFAR